# how to do general conversion of date from different formats (some times with extra string) to Y-m-d format

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter application, I am getting date in different formats, such as: `April 1st 2017`, `May 29, 2015`, `Jun-15-2015`, `10-September-2015` and sometimes even with extra string such as `Start: April 1, 2017`. However, I want to convert the input date from any format to `Y-m-d` in order to save it in MySQL database. For example, if input date is `April 1st 2017` I should get `2017-04-01`. I have used below posted code for that but it is not working for all of the above mentioned cases. So please tell how can I write general conversion logic that can convert date from any format even if date has extra string with it (as mentioned above) to `Y-m-d` format.

**Code:**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F jS Y', $old_date);
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$old_date = 'Jun-15-2015';
echo $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the extra string like

```
$date = str_replace('Start: ',' ',$date);
```

And after you can use `date` function of `php`

```
echo $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help even for inserting this date format into database tables

```
function convertUTCCombinedToLocal($utcDateTime) {

    $utcDateTime = explode(" ", $utcDateTime);
    $date = explode("-", $utcDateTime[0]);
    $time = explode(":", $utcDateTime[1]);

    $localDate = new DateTime();
    $localDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $localDate->setDate($date[0], $date[1], $date[2]);
    if (count($time) == 3) {
        $localDate->setTime($time[0], $time[1], $time[2]);
    } else {
        $localDate->setTime($time[0], $time[1], '00');
    }

    $localDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
    return $localDate->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
}
```